# throw exception and then catch vs duplicate error handling

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, code-readability

I have a code logic as below:

```
// Option 1
try {
   String result = x.getResult();
   if (result == null) {
     // some handling
     logger.error("xxx");
   }
} catch (Throwable t) {
   // some handling
  logger.error("xxx", t);
}
```

In the if and catch block, the handling and logging logic duplicates. We can change it to

```
// Option 2
try {
   String result = x.getResult();
   if (result == null) {
     throw new RuntimeException("yyy");
   }
} catch (Throwable t) {
   // some handling
  logger.error("xxx", t);
}
```

I feel creating an exception and then immediately catch it is just for code readability. However, this is an more expensive operation. Is option 2 better than option 1?

Comment: No.  This is not how exceptions should be used.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't throw an exception just to streamline your code. How about merging them like this:

```
String result = null;
try {
    result = x.getResult();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    // fall through
}
if (result == null) {
    // some handling
    logger.error("xxx", t);
}
```

Comment: the throwable is not capture. If we have a variable `Throwable cause = null` we will log the null cause

Comment: Oh, I missed that. In that case, your approaches are not equivalent. I would just stick with option 1. If there's a lot of duplicated code, extract it to a method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
        String result = x.getResult();
      /*  if (result == null) { < -- Code not need it
            throw new RuntimeException("yyy");
        }*/
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // some handling
        logger.error("xxx", t);
    }
```

yeah 2 option is better, less duplicate code that is all.
U can remove the if sentence and then be sure on the catch u have the Exception type that u are expecting. If not then use Throwable.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzK4ZXa2Tbc <-- check this

Comment: Doing what the author suggests, the OP won't necessarily have his exception thrown if result is null. As such, the handling would not run